# Can I limit buffering in jwplayer

Tags: html, http, video, video-streaming, jwplayer

When using jwplayer to stream mp4 over http using  the html5 version of the player is it possible to limit how much of the video is buffered at any point?

For instance is it possible to tell jwplayer to only buffer 30 seconds ahead?

This is not for content protection but rather I stream a lot of videos that have an opening and ending sequence which the user will likely skip, and I see no reason to transfer data that they wont use both because of the cost to me and the bandwidth use on the users end.

If JwPlayer is unable are there any other similar video players which could accomplish this task?

Comment: I believe buffer control is possible only when using RTMP streaming.

Comment: Thanks for the comment that sucks but i suppose we cant have everything that we want.

Comment: Indeed, there is a variable called bufferlength, which you can set to a #, but that is only for RTMP.

Comment: Thanks Ethan is this a limitation of JW player or an intrinsic limitation of my delivery method of mp4 over http?

Comment: The player doesn't support it, but there might be a way to limit requests server side.